# Using xDebug with Atom

Tags: debugging, xdebug, atom-editor

I new in using xDebug. I am trying to use xDebug with Atom. I am using Linux Mint as OS. My `phpinfo` output is as like below

[image]

My Atom settings is as like below

[image]

I installed xDebug successfully.

[image]

My Atom is view is like below

[image]

I am using browser extension also

[image]

How can I debug using xDebug in Atom ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your php.ini file and paste this all the way at the bottom:

```
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

And remove the `;` before `zend_extension`.

Comment: Thanks @Mike Deluca. Your this line `xdebug.remote_host=localhost` helps me. Thanks.

Comment: 5 years later the config has changed: [Upgrade guide](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide) 
`xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1 
xdebug.client_port=9003` and others...